# How to find entrypoint of an Application Client

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a `tool based on Java EE 6` project, where client tier is built in `Swing`. The tool has multiple ui modules and no matter which ui I run, it always starts with the same jPanel (login ui and then welcome page). There is no main() or run() in the corresponding java code. 
I am new to Swing and am having trouble finding the flow of application. What is the analogous of `index.html` of a web tier in application tier ?

Comment: Does the JAR file contain a manifest file?  I might be in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.  If so can you post the contents.  If it's not in META-INF can you recursively search the JAR file starting at the root for "manifest"

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli The entire application is divided into three modules `Admin Tool`, `EJB Module` and `EAR Module`. Only `EAR module` has `Manifest.MF` but there is nothing inside it except version